# Insuff. permissions to download Audacity plugins?

Tags: permissions, files, directory, plugins, audacity

I'm trying to download Audacity plugins (.ny files) to my plug-ins folder at usr/share/audacity/plugins but it once I try to download it, it says insufficient permissions?

I can't copy/paste any files into the folder either.

I'm administrator, why can't I change the files? How else can I add plugins? How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a GUI file browser or are you using the CLI commands like `cp`/`mv`?

Comment: @OwenHines GUI file browser

Answer (score 1):

If if you still want to use your GUI file browser for file transferring then you have to run the file browser itself as `root`. This means that you have to go in terminal and type

```
sudo nameOfFileBrowser
```

And obviously replace nameOfFileBrowser with whatever file browser you are using. The reason for this is because even though you are considered an administrator, you're running the file manager as a non-administrator. Also, **don't make running the file manager as root a habit.** Only run your file manager as root when you have to. Otherwise, you could modify some sensitive files such as system ones, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are an "administrator" does not mean you are `root`. In any case, using Linux as `root` is not recommended, but you can copy the plugins in place by following this:

- Given that your username is `john` and your home directory is `/home/john`, create a subdirectory in it, called `audacity-plugins`. Thus, the directory would be `/home/john/audacity-plugins`.
- Copy your plugins to this directory.
- Next, open the terminal and type in this:
  `sudo cp /home/john/audacity-plugins/* /usr/share/audacity/plugins/`

This will copy your plugins to the required directory. Note that, as for all sudo commands, you will have to enter your password (think about it as a kind of Windows UAC).